# Watch a sexpr for edits

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'd like to tell Emacs to 'watch' a particular form (identified by its `car`) within a buffer and evaluate it whenever I edit it.

One approach I can think of is to add a function to `post-self-insert-hook`, which would find and parse the targeted form and compare it with its previously stored state.

It doesn't sound *too* inefficient, especially if a 'calls per second' maximum is enforced (e.g. using `current-time`).

**Is there is a higher level / more idiomatic way to accomplish this?** It sounds like the sort of problem that has been solved already.

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but given that you are talking about manual editing, can you confirm that `C-M-x` (i.e. `eval-defun`) is definitely not an appropriate solution?

Comment: I normally evaluate stuff that way (i.e. manually) but the point of my question is how to automate this process for certain forms.

Comment: I'm with wvxvw on this one. Contrary to the final paragraph, I'd honestly be a bit surprised if anyone has tried to "solve" this before. If you're editing an expression it will likely pass through numerous valid and invalid states, and only you know when it's *actually* ready to be re-evaluated. As such, this is necessarily a manual task (certainly in the general case, at least). If you're adamant that you want this, an example would probably be useful, because as it is this does indeed sound bizarre.

Comment: You raise a very valid point. There is Light Table, a forthcoming IDE (primarily for Clojure) which in fact auto-evaluates *all* forms as you edit them. Surely some heuristic is used (e.g. only eval 10 seconds after the user has stopped typing). As long as the targeted forms don't involve I/O, there aren't a lot of risks in evaluating potentially broken/incomplete code.

Comment: This question basically screams "Light Table". :) But from what I can see from the public alpha, they switched over to a more manual model, which already works in Emacs: press `Ctrl-Enter` to eval the form, press `Ctrl-Shift-Enter` to eval the entire file.

Answer (score 3):

I think the most natural way is to create an overlay that would span from the beginning to the end of the form.

Overlays have a [modification-hooks](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Overlay-Properties.html#Overlay-Properties) property, and you can add a watcher function to it.

The overlay will contract or expand appropriately if you modify buffer contents strictly inside it, but you'll need to decide what to do when buffer is edited at the edges of the form. See `insert-in-front-hooks`, `insert-behind-hooks` and the last two arguments to [make-overlay](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Managing-Overlays.html#Managing-Overlays). I'd probably just re-create the overlay in most of these cases, just to be sure about the new bounds.

About the "calls per second" thing, you can use [run-with-idle-timer](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Idle-Timers.html).

Answer (score 2):

Part of what [@Dmitry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/615245/dmitry) mentioned can be turn into simple prototype. Mark `(message "text")` and run <kbd>M-x</kbd>`eval-on-modify-add`

```
(defun eval-on-modify-add ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((ov (make-overlay (region-beginning) (region-end))))
    (overlay-put ov 'modification-hooks '(eval-on-modify-execute))))

(defun eval-on-modify-execute (ov &optional flag &rest rv)
  (if flag
      (eval-region (overlay-start ov) (overlay-end ov))))

(message "test")
```